# where to find iPhone device UDID? if iTunes expected to be retired by macOS 10.15, expected to be announced in wwdc19

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, udid

I have been using iTunes to find my iPhone device UDID for iOS development, iTunes is expected to be retired in macOS 10.15 expected to be announced in wwdc19 on June 03. where else in my Mac I can find the device UDID? please list all the possible ways local device, remote device...

I don't know.

Comment: itunes will be replaced : check https://www.techspot.com/news/80320-apple-expected-retire-itunes-wwdc-next-week.html

Comment: you can find your UDID from here also https://get.udid.io/

Answer (score 15):

You can find UDID from XCode.

- After connecting the device to XCode, Go To:  XCode -> Window -> Devices
  and Simulators
- Select the connected device
- See "Identifier" from information on right side

[image: XCode]

Answer (score 6):

Connect the iOS Devices to Mac.

Open Xcode, 
Window menu
Devices and Simulators (⇧⌘2)
Devices tab (Devices and Simulators) 
Select the iOS Device 
UDID is displayed next to the Identifier. 
copy it, use it for development...

---

### Xcode > Window menu > Devices and Simulators (⇧⌘2) > Devices > select iPhone Device > Identifier (this is the device UDID) > select the text > Copy > Done.

iTunes is not needed, Xcode is sufficient.

Comment: Where is the Window menu in Xcode 14? But ⇧⌘2 still works! thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are a simple and easy way to find the UDID.

Just open the URL in safari : - https://get.udid.io and then click on Get UDID Button

You can get UDID of Remote devices no Need to be connect the iPhone,iPad,iPod to a Desktop.

Comment: @Aruna check again the given url

Comment: thanks for updating the url, (earlier it was getudid.io), https://get.udid.io seems to be working. thanks.

Comment: This doesn't show the correct UDID for iPhones created in Simulators. Still need to go through XCode. 
ie. Xcode > Window menu > Devices and Simulators (⇧⌘2) > Devices > select iPhone Device > Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

**Use macOS Finder**:

(At least as of macOS Big Sur 11.6.1 which I've used for this example.)

1. Connect iPhone via lightning cable and **complete all trust prompts on both devices** (macOS laptop/desktop *and* iOS iPhone device).
2. Launch a Finder window in any number of ways.
3. In the left pane of the Finder window, **locate your iPhone device and select it**.
4. After the main right pane of the Finder window populates your device's information, ***click on the iPhone model text** below your device's name* towards the top of the main right pane.

   - e.g. iPhone 12 mini
5. Observe the additional information that is revealed including the device's serial number and UDID.

   - Clicking on this section of text multiple times will cycle through additional device info until it returns to the original view with model name, storage capacity, and charge level.

Answer (score 0):

You can know your device UDID from pandahelper here the link : https://pandahelp.vip , after you enter the website tap on iOS Download Tap Vip version it will ask for profile install tap accept install it by go to settings > general > VPN you will see the profile tap on it and tap install enter your device password install and it will redirect you to the website you will see your device udid at upper right.

Comment: I don't know if this works, but I would advise against installing a 3rd party certificate unless you are really sure you can trust it.